# Multiple figures in single figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create four (largely identical) plots in R and combined into a single .png file to insert into a presentation.

I am using ggplot2.

I have to do a bit of data-wrangling first based on a single test value.  Thus I have created a function (with the test value as the argument) and then assign the resulting figure to a figure object.

eg

```
Fig1 = RDDPlot('2010-05-02')
Fig2 = RDDPlot('2010-06-02')
Fig3 = RDDPlot('2010-07-02')
Fig4 = RDDPlot('2010-08-02')
```

I am trying to use `par()` as per:
https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html
and
[Multiple scatterplot figure in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989000/multiple-scatterplot-figure-in-r)

but all these example use plot and are done on a single line.  I am building my plot up with multiple statements (eg combinations of scatterplot with vline, mean lines etc), so it is easier for me to assign to a figure object and then layout the objects in a (2,2).

The following does not work for me:

```
png(paste0(path,'Plot.png'),width=12.8,height=9.6,units="cm",res=1200)

  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  Fig1
  Fig2
  Fig3
  Fig4

dev.off()
```

It just produces a .png with only Fig1 on it...

Comment: Convenient programming solution after plotting the 4 figures but outside R is imagemagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `grid.arrange` from the package of `gridExtra` and then save the plot using `ggsave`:

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p = grid.arrange(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, Fig1, Fig2, Fig3, Fig4)

ggsave(plot = p, filename = "Plot.png", units = "cm", height = 9.6, width = 12.8, dpi = 1200 )
```

Comment: That is perfect!  Thank you so much.  Any way of slightly reducing white space around them so that they look as big as possible?

Comment: You can play with the argument `plot.margin` in the `theme` command.

Comment: You can check here for the use of `plot.margin` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556068/removing-all-the-space-between-two-ggplots-combined-with-grid-arrange

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the link.  I am an R newbie, so this cuts down my trial and error! Love SO people!  Racing to finalise a presentation...

Comment: Glad to be bale to help you. Good luck with the presentation